Need to test an async function that contains multiple async calls. How to mock these calls?
I have a function I need to test
example:
async def post(self):
    #bunch of calls

    try:
        var = await another_func(x, y) #returns int value
        if var != 1:
            raise exception
    except:
        return ...

    #bunch of more calls

I need to test this post call but I need the 'another_func' to return a 1 so that an exception doesn't get raised and I can test the functionality of the rest of the code.
I tried this:
@mock.patch('path.another_func', new_callable=mock.AsyncMock)
    async def test_the_call(
        self, mock_another_func
    ):
        exp_res = #some json

        #Mocking to bypass this call to test the rest of the code
        mock_another_func.return_value = 1       

        (body, _, _) = await self.post(self.path, body=json.dumps(self.body)) #the mocked function gets called here

        response = json.loads(body)
        assert response == exp_res

But another_func doesnt return an int value but a mock. Hence my check fails (if var !=1) and raises an exception and hence says that my code is not json serializable.
how do i fix this?
Also my code is supposed to run in containers where I dont have explicit liberty to use exceptional python modules. So ideally I need a basic answer but any responses appreciated.

I cannot reproduce your problem given what you show in your question. If I create app.py like this:
async def another_func():
    return -1


async def post():
    # bunch of calls

    try:
        var = await another_func()  # returns int value
        if var != 1:
            raise Exception()
    except Exception:
        return False

    return True

And test_app.py like this:
import pytest
from unittest import mock

import app


@mock.patch("app.another_func", new_callable=mock.AsyncMock)
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_post(mock_func):
    mock_func.return_value = 1
    res = await app.post()
    assert res


@mock.patch("app.another_func", new_callable=mock.AsyncMock)
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_post_failure(mock_func):
    mock_func.return_value = 2
    res = await app.post()
    assert not res

Then the tests succeed as expected:
$ pytest -v
=========================== test session starts ===========================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.4, pytest-8.3.2, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: asyncio-0.23.8
asyncio: mode=Mode.STRICT
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_app.py::test_post PASSED                                       [ 50%]
test_app.py::test_post_failure PASSED                               [100%]

============================ 2 passed in 0.01s ============================

In particular, the post function returns successfully when the mocked return value for another_func is 1, and fails as expected when the mocked return value of another_func is not 1.
